Google Routes API - Field mask results in empty response
I'm trying to make a POST request to https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes with a field mask like in the documentation to only get the data I need.
It works well with most fields, but there are two fields (routes.legs.steps.startLocation and routes.legs.steps.endLocation) that result in empty responses.
This is strange because when I use a field mask of "*", I can see the startLocation and endLocation data in the response.
Another thing is that this only happens when travelMode: TRANSIT is set.
Example request:
curl -X POST "https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "X-Goog-FieldMask: routes.legs.steps.endLocation" \
    -H "X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY" \
    -d '{
        "origin": {
            "location": {
                "latLng": {
                    "latitude": 40.748817,
                    "longitude": -73.985428
                }
            }
        },
        "destination": {
            "location": {
                "latLng": {
                    "latitude": 40.758896,
                    "longitude": -73.985130
                }
            }
        },
        "travelMode": "TRANSIT"
    }'

Response:
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "legs": [
        {
          "steps": [
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


For this kind of issue, it is best to open a support ticket at: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Oh so this is a bug in the API? I thought I was doing something wrong.
